# Image not displaying (but loading) in PDF generation using resource stream

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I created a PDF using PDFBOX. The entire PDF generates perfectly and even the images loaded while i was using

```
PDImageXObject ptabelle = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("src/main/resources/pdf/ptabelle.png", pdDocument);
```

But the project will need to go live sometime so I have to replace the static path with a class loader. After doing all that the PDF generates, the text is displayed, but not the image.

The interesting thing is that inside the PDF the "box" where the image should be is there, but not the image.

[image: Box where image should be]

Here is the code for the stream generation.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
PDStream pdStream = new PDStream(pdDocument, classLoader.getResourceAsStream("pdf/ptabelle.png"));
PDResources pdResources = new PDResources();
PDImageXObject ptabelle = new PDImageXObject(pdStream, pdResources);

PDPageContentStream pdPageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocument, page4);
```

And here is the call in the code, the length + width variables are defined in the code.

```
 pdPageContentStream.drawImage(ptabelle, TEXT_BEGIN, currentYCoord, 172, 107);
```

Comment: Please change your code so that you use the factory classes, for png this would be `LosslessFactory`. I.e. first load the image in a BufferedImage with `ImageIO.read()`, then call `LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc,bufferedImage)`. Does this work?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr - Thank you very much sir, that did the trick perfectly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `new PDImageXObject(pdStream, pdResources)` which is for PDFBox internal use, please use the appropriate `LosslessFactory` method. So your code would look like this:

```
BufferedImage bim = ImageIO.read(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("pdf/ptabelle.png"));
PDImageXObject img = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(pdDocument, bim);
```

See also the javadoc of [PDImageXObject.createFromFileByExtension](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.html#createFromFileByExtension(java.io.File,%20org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument)), which explains what factory methods can be called instead.